# click submit or press enter to act up on jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a chat app. and I want the message to be displayed wither the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click the submit button. Every thing is working fine with the submit button but I can't figure how to combine the two possibilities(<kbd>Enter</kbd> & Submit): here is my code for the submit:

```
    $(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var userName = $("#userName").val();
        var textcontent = $("#content").val();  and so on..
```

Thanks much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the event handler for submit to named function which can be reused then attach this function for submit button's `click` event and your chat message input's `keyup` event.

```
function sendChatMessage(){
    // Your logic here..

}

$("#submit").click(sendChatMessage);
$("#yourMessageInputId").keyup(function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode === 13) { // 13 is the key code for enter.
        sendChatMessage();
    }
})
```

Or just trigger click event of the button when pressed key is enter, without changing any other code:

```
$("#yourMessageInputId").keyup(function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode === 13) { // 13 is the key code for enter.
        $("#submit").click();
    }
})
```

EDIT: [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EKs8D/)

Comment: Today I found that IE doesn't fire `keyup` event on `enter` pressing. You should use `keydown` event which is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `submit` event instead of `click` event. Here is example :

```
$(function(){
   $("#submit").submit(function(){
   var username = $("#userName").val();
   // and so on..
  });
 });
```

Comment: yes but how to combine this with the possibility of pressing Enter??  changing click to submit still allows Enter.  I want the Enter to be considered as submit.

Answer (score 0):

more cooler:

```
$(function(){
 $("#submit").on('submit', function(){
  var username = $("#userName").val();
  // and so on..
 });
});
```

The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form. Forms can be submitted either by clicking an explicit `<input type="submit">`, `<input type="image">`, or `<button type="submit">`, or by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> when certain form elements have focus.

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/doniyor/7Ttkh/